# Is it possible to create split editors inside individual tabs in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, tabs

I'm wondering if it is possible to split a tab up in VS Code in the same way it works in VS 2017. In essence I only want to see the split for the file that is in focus. In VS Code when I have two files open with the first split then view the second file the first file tab is still showing but I only want to see the whole of the second file.
Hope this makes sense. I've included a screenshot to demonstrate the differences.

Another way to phrase this is that I basically want editor groups *inside* tabs.

[image: Screen shot of both programs with tabs]

Comment: Well I guess it' not possible then :(

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69111951/836330

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, this is not super well supported in vanilla VS Code (I.e. with no extensions) at the time of this writing.

There is the `View: Split Editor in Group` command which was [introduced in version 1.61](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_61#_split-an-editor-without-creating-a-new-group), which you can access from the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette), and is bound by default to <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>,<kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>, and also accessible from the context menu of the tab handle. It seems to only allow splitting horizontally, and only split the same text document.

There's a quite popular feature-request issue ticket covering what you're looking for (if I understand correctly): [Allow to open two distinct editors side by side in one group #36700](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/36700). You can give it a thumbs up reaction to show support for it and subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. Please refrain from making noisy comments like "+1" / "bump".

In that discussion thread, someone wrote an extension that they claim provides a solution, which perhaps you could try out: [`agquick.workviews`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=agquick.workviews) <sup><sub>(I have no affiliation with that extension)</sub></sup>.

There's also a similar feature-request here that you might be interested in doing the same for: [Tabs that group editor grid layouts (Vim-style tabs) #143024](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/143024).

For your reference / learning purposes, I found the above issue tickets by googling "`github vscode issues split inside tab`".